# Bash - Command substitution adds single quotes

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, command-substitution

I have a problem with bash behavior while evaluating grave accents. I want to run find with optional -name:

```
find -name "*.log"
```

works fine, but when i want to get the -name part from nested script

```
find `echo "-name \"*.log\""`
```

it simply does not work. Running it under bash -x shows, that this command is evaluated to

```
find -name '"*.log"'
```

Apparently its because of this single quotes. Is there some workaround to get rid of them?
Best regards.

//requested OS and bash version:
Debian, 7.8 wheezy,
Bash 4.2.37(1)-release

Comment: `find $(echo '-name "*.log"')`?

Comment: Still `find -name '"*.log"'`.

Comment: Please add name of operating system, version and output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` to your question.

Comment: `set -f` and `find $(echo '-name *.log')` works, however not disabling wildcard expansion would probably be a better solution

Comment: This sounds a lot like [bash faq 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash has not added single quotes to the command. The single quotes that you see are added to make displayed command be valid bash syntax. If you see

```
find -name '"*.log"'
```

it means that bash was told to execute this command: `find` with two arguments `-name` and `"*.log"` (the double quotes being part of the argument). It could have been input exactly like this or in some other equivalent way like

```
find -name \"*.log\"
find -name "\"*.log\""
find -name '"*.'log""\"
```

Now let's look at what you wrote:

```
find `echo "-name \"*.log\""`
```

The command running in the subshell is

```
echo "-name \"*.log\""
```

Its output is

```
-name "*.log"
```

That's where the double quotes in the argument come from. When the output of a command substitution is interpolated into a command line, it is not parsed as shell syntax — so for example

```
find `echo '; rm -rf ~'`
```

will not delete all your files but instead pass `;` as the first argument to `find`, `rm` as the second, `-rf` as the third and your home directory (assuming it doesn't contain any special characters) as the fourth.

When a variable substitution or a command substitution is outside double quotes, the following transformations happen to the variable's value or the command's output:

1. For command substitution only: trailing newlines are stripped.
2. The string is broken up into whitespace-delimited pieces. (You can configure the delimiters by setting the `IFS` variable.) Note that the result of this transformation is a *list* of strings.
3. Each element of the list is interpreted as a wildcard pattern. If that pattern matches files, then the element is replaced by the list of matching files (this is called [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))). If the pattern doesn't match any file, the element is left alone.

Step 2 breaks the string `-name "*.log"` into two pieces: `-name` and `"*.log"`. Neither piece matches any file so the result is the two words `-name` and `"*.log"`.

What you meant to do is instead run `find` with the arguments `-name` and `*.log`. You can do this by turning off globbing:

```
set -f
find `echo -name *.log`
set +f
```

This is not robust: it won't let you pass file names containing whitespace, for example. Generally speaking, you should not attempt to build commands by storing bits of them in a variable or passing them around in commands. The best way to do what you're doing depends on what you're actually trying to do. Here's some general advice:

- [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score -1):

Use function eval, this will resolve your issue

```
command="find `echo \"-name \"*.log\"\"`"   response=$(eval "$command")
```